# How can i refer to the elements of the nested list in C# using Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, generics

I have a function that handles the generic where the generic is represented by a list or a nested lists structure like this:

```
List<List<int>> = ( (1, 2, 3, 4), (0, 1, 2, 3) )
```

i want to refer to each element of each list and apply some method to it, for example

```
public int Increment(int i)
{ 
    return ++i;
}

public List<T> Run(List<T> items)
{
    return items.AsParallel().Select(item => Increment(item).ToList();
}
```

So, for the "Increment" method, I would like to get a list of lists like i had

```
((1, 2, 3, 4), (0, 1, 2, 3))
```

and get

```
((2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4))
```

I would like not to depend on the amount of nesting and have one method that goes to the final elements of nested lists

Comment: It would be nice if you provided actual sample code that demonstrated what you're trying to achieve. It's not clear to me what "basic element" you are referring to when your example is a `List<List<List<int>>>`. Is it the innermost `int` value? Also, *where* in the code above do you want to access the "basic element"? And what does `SomeFunc` return?

Comment: Either, Can you specify where do you need that base? Because you can wirte something like SomeFunc<int> maybe

Comment: I do not understand this question at all. Why did you show us the declaration for `Run`? You don't use it anywhere in your examples. And what does this question have to do with LINQ?

Comment: @RufusL i changed the question

Comment: @Emanuele, i changed the question

Comment: @JohnWu, i changed the question

Comment: @Neironari Are you sure you want AsParallel? How much elements into input data?

Comment: I suppose you could use reflection on the type to see if it implements `IEnumerable`, but you'd have an issue with `List<List<string>>`, since `string` also implements that interface. Do you haver a practical example of what you're trying to accomplish? Perhaps there's a better way...

Comment: @Genusatplay, i try to make something like something like a class library with a specific functionality and parallel processing would be less dependent on the size of the input data

Comment: For simple work like increment using AsParallel will be slower than simple foreach.

Comment: @Genusatplay it's just an example, the main question is to access each element of the list

Comment: @RufusL I'm trying to make a method that takes a collection and some function, and apply that function to each element of a nested list structure. I also try to achieve maximum independence from data type and nesting size.

Comment: I understand that, my question is *why*? What is the concrete problem you're trying to solve. What is the exact scenario you find yourself in that makes you want to implement such a thing? Sometimes people ask how to do some specific thing when really they should be asking how to solve some specific problem. This is often referred to as an [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Generic method which takes the list and the function as parameters.

```
List<List<T>> Run<T>(List<List<T>> items, Func<T,T> f){
    return items.Select(item => item.Select(item2 => f(item2)).ToList()).ToList();
}
```

Called like so: `var ret = Run(list, Increment);`

For different nesting levels you could create overloads such as.

```
List<List<List<T>>> Run<T>(List<List<List<T>>> items, Func<T,T> f){
    return items.Select(item => item.Select(item2 => item2.Select(item3 => f(item3)).ToList()).ToList()).ToList();
}
```

Called the same way, the compiler will automatically resolve the correct overload method.

Comment: i know about overloading, but i want to be more independent from level of nesting in lists.

Comment: If you're nesting lists so deeply that you can't write overloads for the first N levels of nesting, are lists really the right tool for the job?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, maybe i am a fool.
I realized that a generic-based method provides type safety by the way and that if I want to implement iteration over internal lists, I should change the behavior of the delegate that I pass to the method.
instead of changing Run method i have to change Increment method for special realization

```
static List<int> Increment(List<int> listInt)
{
    return listInt.Select(x => x + 1).ToList();
}
```

or

```
 static List<List<int>> Increment(List<List<int>> listInt)
 {
    return listInt.Select(x => x.Select(y => y + 1).ToList()).ToList();
 }
```

My parallel iteration method remains unchanged

```
public List<T> Run(List<T> items, Func<T, T> action)
{
    return items.AsParallel().Select(item => action(item)).ToList();
}
```